# Oracle Weblogic server 14c compliance

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am learning to work with oracle weblogic server .After searching and reading about it, I am still unclear on these.So I would like your help to know the following :

1. I know that weblogic server 14c is fully compatible to work with Java EE 8. Are there any other JDK versions that are compatible with weblogic server 14c  ??
2. While upgrading from other weblogic server versions to weblogic 14.1.1, is it possible to manage/change the JDK version using the reconfiguration wizard itself or in any other way?

Could you please provide clarification for the above. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEE 8 is not a JDK but a framework. WebLogic Server 14c can run with Java (jdk) 8 and 11.
No, the reconfiguration wizard does not provie a way to change the JVM/JDK used by your server instances. You have to manually change your scripts.

Comment: May I Know if it supports Open JDK, IBM's JDK or any other type of JDK ? Or only Oracle's JDK?

Comment: You should refer to the [certification matrix](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fmw-141100-certmatrix-6400512.xlsx) for this kind of question.
WebLogic Server 14c is only supported with Oracle's JDK and with IBM JDKs when running on AIX. OpenJDK is not supported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70786056/6120034